# Jquery UI Draggable element top issue due to position relative

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am using jquery UI in one of my project where I fetch the co-ordinates of dragged item and later use it to draw the text on canvas.

However the *dynamically* created *draggable element* position themselves relatively and the 2nd element always gives undesired css *top* and *left*value as it is related to 1st element.

Is there a way to change the position property or any other method to achieve top and left values related to parent.

Here is a ***[codepen](https://codepen.io/anishjana/pen/RwrPowR)*** , where you can see the 2nd element gives negative top value when I drag above the current position.

Setting up the draggable components:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".drag" ).draggable({
       containment: ".container",
       scroll: false,
       drag: function() {
         let top = $(this).css("top");
        let left = $(this).css("left");
      let index = $(this).data("index");   
        if(index == "1") {
          document.getElementById("one").innerText = "top: " + top + " left:" + left;
        }else {
           document.getElementById("two").innerText = "top: " + top + " left:" + left;
        }

       }

    });
  });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Would suggest using `.position()`, `.offset()`, or the `ui.position` that is passed to the `drag` callback. See: https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-drag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".drag").draggable({
    containment: ".container",
    scroll: false,
    drag: function(e, ui) {
      var self = $(this);
      var parent = $(".container");
      var pos = self.position();
      // Adjust for position of parent and border, gives Inner position
      pos.left = pos.left - parent.offset().left - 2;
      pos.top = pos.top - parent.offset().top - 2;
      $("#" + self.data("index")).html("top: " + pos.top + " left:" + pos.left);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px red solid;
  margin: 4rem auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.drag {
  background: orange;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: move;
  &:hover {
    background: darken(orange, 5);
  }
}

h5, p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="draggable-1" data-index="one" class="drag">
    <p>One</p>
  </div>
  <div id="draggable-2" data-index="two" class="drag">
    <p>two</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="info">
  <h5> 1st element: </h5>
  <p id="one"></p>
  <br/>
  <h5> 2nd element: </h5>
  <p id="two"></p>
</div>
```

Using the dragged elements `.position()`, we can see it's `top` and `left` relative to `0,0` on the page. We just have to adjust this for the position of the container. `.offset()` will give the actual points for `top` and `left` since the element has a margin. `.position()` would report it's at `0,0` on the page.

See More:

- https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/
- https://api.jquery.com/position/
- https://api.jquery.com/offset/